# How to make extendible ArrayList?

Tags: java

At the moment I'm working on a game and things are going pretty good. What keeps me busy at the moment, is making a mob spawner which spawns mobs in a certain area.

The big problem is right now, I'm not really sure how to keep track of all the mobs being spawned by the spawner, as there are different inheritances of mobs.

This is my MobSpawner class:

```
public class MobSpawner {

    protected List<Mob> mobs;

    protected Level level;

    protected int timer = 0;
    protected int spawnTime = 0;
    protected int maxMobs = 0;

    public MobSpawner(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

}
```

And this is my RoachSpawner class:

```
public class RoachSpawner extends MobSpawner {

    public RoachSpawner(Level level) {
        super(level);
        mobs = new ArrayList<Roach>(); // Roach is an extension of Mob
    }

}
```

This is not gonna work because the List and ArrayList must be of the same type.

So the question is, does anyone have any other ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How and where is `mobs` being used?

Comment: It's going to be used to keep track of how many mobs the spawner has spawned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm presuming that `Roach extends Mob`.

You can use an `ArrayList<Mob>` to hold `Roach`es. So:

```
public RoachSpawner(Level level) {
    super(level);
    mobs = new ArrayList<Mob>();
}
```

And if you just use `ArrayList<Mob>` in all the implementations, you can allocate it in the base instead (assuming `ArrayList` is always the container you want -- if you want to use other `List` types see kwah's answer and have subclasses create list):

```
public class MobSpawner {

    protected final List<Mob> mobs = new ArrayList<Mob>();

    ...

}
```

And just have the subclasses use the base's list.

Instantiating the list in the base class and making it `final` has a bonus side-effect of letting you state the following invariants (presuming you don't violate them with reflection or anything):

- A `MobSpawner` will never have a null `mobs`, and
- `mobs` will reference the same object throughout the entire lifetime of a `MobSpawner`.

Being able to make those assumptions can possibly simplify some of your logic in other places.

Making it `final` also enforces, at compile time, that you're not inadvertently replacing it with another list somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right, it's just really simple as I read it now. Really clear solution :D! I guess the majority of my problem is my need to sleep (it's 2.42 am), so I guess I'd better get to sleep! Thanks again for your idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already doing so, try taking advantage of supertypes.

In the same way that you can declare a variable to be a `List` and then instantiate it to be an `ArrayList`, try saying your `List` contains `Character` items and then fill it with specific implementations of the Characters (eg `List<Character>` is instantiated as `ArrayList<Mob>` and `ArrayList<Roach>`).

```
public abstract class Character { }

public class Mob extends Character { }
public class Roach extends Character { }



public class Spawner {
    protected List<? extends Character> characters;
    protected Level level;
    protected int timer = 0;
    protected int spawnTime = 0;
    protected int maxCharacters = 0;

    public Spawner(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

}



public class RoachSpawner extends Spawner {
    public RoachSpawner(Level level) {
        super(level);
        mobs = new ArrayList<Roach>();
    }

}

public class MobSpawner extends Spawner {
    public RoachSpawner(Level level) {
        super(level);
        mobs = new ArrayList<Mob>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code would not compile. `ArrayList<Roach>` does not match `List<Character>`. Change `characters` to `List<? extends Character>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ah, it has been a while since I last delved into Java... Would having Character be an interface be an alternative solution?

Comment: No. Base class vs. interface has no effect on matching. You still have to use the wildcard there.